# Calculate average restaurant rating in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a restaurants table with the following fields

```
Schema::create('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('menu');
            $table->string('hours');
            $table->string('contact');
            $table->string('payment');
```

include rating_count which stores average rating which i added later

[i have a reviews table which stores the rating of each restaurant]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXudX.png
i want to calculate the average rating of each restaurant and display it on the restaurants view as a number

Comment: The screenshot you provided has no numeric field, how will you calculate an average?

Comment: @Jerodev  it does the rating column

Comment: Is there any particular reason this post is marked with `jquery` tag?

Comment: Okay, maybe you should include that. Also, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: the review blade contains jquery code

Comment: @MatildahMariwa : it doesn't really seem that you're looking for javascript/jQuery solution. I'd recommend to put `php` tag instead to attract more people capable to give the answer you've been after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to set the relationship in your Restaurant model like this:

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

Then to calculate the rating you can add another method:

```
public function rating()
{
    $totalReviews = $this->reviews->count();

    if($totalReviews)
    {
        $totalRating = $this->reviews->sum('rating');

        return number_format($totalRating / $totalReviews, 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::find(1)->with('reviews');

$restaurant->rating(); // should give you what you need.
```

-- EDIT

Add accessor like this in your Restaurant model:

```
protected $appends = ['rating_count'];

public function getRatingCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->reviews->avg('rating');
}
```

Then to use it :

```
$restaurant->rating_count;
```

Comment: should i put the method rating on the restaurant model or on the controller model?

Comment: in the Restaurant model, yes.

Comment: i need to store the rating of every restaurant in a column called rating_count in the restaurants table

Comment: It does not make sense to store that value in the table, because each time a review is entered you will need to update the table. That's more like a computed property, take a look at my edit, and use that instead.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: how do i put the rating count to round to two decimal places?

Comment: @MatildahMariwa use `number_format($restaurant->rating_count, 2);`.

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly better to keep your methods defining relationships as easy as possible in your restaurant model.

```
public function reviews() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}
```

Now you can use this relation to get the rate, You can add a property which is not a column in your model as an appended property.

```
protected $appends = ['rate'];
```

and then have a function to assign the value :

```
public functions getRateAttribute() {
     return $this->reviews->avg('rate') ?? 0;
}
```

The problem with this is, an appended property as the name suggests is always appended to the instance of the model.

So if you just do following :

```
$restaurant= Restaurant::first();
```

Even if you do not need rate, laravel will still have `$restaurant->rate` ready for you and because of which it will do the average query.

Also a heads up on Laravel's `avg('column_name')`:

- It gives null when no data is present
- It gives value something like 0.0 if you average a non-numeric column
- Gives valid value in format 3.9265 if the value is present which is more than 2 decimal points (mostly 4)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch out all restaurents with the reviews.

```
$restaurants = Restaurants::with('reviews')->get();
```

Loop over the restaurants and use collection method average to calculate the field.

```
foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
    $restaurant->rating_count = $restaurant->reviews->avg('rating');
    $restaurant->save();
}
```